# Scala filter on two conditions

Tags: arrays, scala, filter, multiple-conditions

I would like to filter my data set on two conditions at once.

Is it possible?

I want something like this:

```
mystuff = mystuff.filter(_.isX && _.name == "xyz")
```

Answer (score 81):

Using slightly less concise lambda syntax:

```
mystuff = mystuff.filter(x => (x.isX && x.name == "xyz"))
```

You can find more detail on Scala anonymous function syntax [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/quick-explanation-of-scalas-syntax).

Comment: does this eliminates the performance overhead? I mean in the end query is this expressed correctly?

Answer (score 10):

While there might be some performance impact depending on what "myStuff" is, you could always filter twice

```
mystuff = mystuff.filter(_.isX).filter(_.name == "xyz")
```

Comment: This causes double looping the whole list.

Comment: @squixy just an FYI, it doesn't. `filter` creates a new projection (or view) of the collection such that when an element is asked for during iteration (i.e. `map`, `fold`, etc...) the `filter` function(s) are applied to see whether the element is returned

Comment: @ThaDon not true - it depends on the collection type but the most common (`Array`, `List`, `Vector`...) will create an intermediate collection

Answer (score 6):

If you need to frequently filter with several predicate, you could define a way of combining them:

```
case class And[A]( p1: A=>Boolean, p2: A=>Boolean ) extends (A=>Boolean) {
  def apply( a: A ) = p1(a) && p2(a)
}
```

Here is how to use it to keep only the odd numbers bigger than 10:

```
scala> (0 until 20) filter And( _ > 10, _ % 2 == 1 )
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
```

It easy to write `Or` and `Not` combinators in the same fashion.

Comment: Does this method have an advantage over using a lambda function `mystuff.filter( each => each.isX && each.name.equals("xyz"))` ?