# Chain Scala Filters Without the Overhead

Tags: scala

I want to chain a bunch of filters but do not want the overhead associated with creating multiple lists.

```
type StringFilter = (String) => Boolean

def nameFilter(value: String): StringFilter = 
    (s: String) => s == value

def lengthFilter(length: Int): StringFilter = 
    (s: String) => s.length == length

val list = List("Apple", "Orange")
```

Problem is this builds a list after each filter:

```
list.filter(nameFilter("Apples")).filter(lengthFilter(5))

// list of string -> list of name filtered string -> list of name and length filtered string
```

I want:

```
// list of string -> list of name and length filtered string
```

I find out which filters are needed at run-time so I must add filters dynamically.

```
// Not sure how to implement add function.
val filterPipe: StringFilter = ???

// My preferred DSL (or very close to it)
filterPipe.add(nameFilter("Apples")
filterPipe.add(lengthFilter(5))

// Must have DSL
list.filter(filterPipe)
```

How can I implement `filterPipe`?

Is there some way to recursively AND the filter conditions together in a filterPipe (which is itself a StringFilter)?

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/a/11128773/3041008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `withFilter`:

```
list.withFilter(nameFilter("Apples")).withFilter(lengthFilter(5))...
```

Comment: ooo...  So `withFilter(filter)` chains them together without creating a new list for each filter?

Comment: Looking at `withFilter` implementation code now, my outlook on Scala keeps getting better!  Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

[A blog post](http://frankthomas.name/blog/2012/08/combining_predicates_in_scala/) suggest another alternative using an implicit class to allow aggregating multiple predicates using custom operators

```
implicit class Predicate[A](val pred: A => Boolean) {
  def apply(x: A) = pred(x)

  def &&(that: A => Boolean) = new Predicate[A](x => pred(x) && that(x))
  def ||(that: A => Boolean) = new Predicate[A](x => pred(x) || that(x))
  def unary_! = new Predicate[A](x => !pred(x))
}
```

Then you can apply the predicate chain as follows

```
list.filter { (nameFilter("Apple") && lengthFilter(5)) (_) }
```

You can also chain the predicates dynamically

```
val list = List("Apple", "Orange", "Meat")
val isFruit = nameFilter("Apple") || nameFilter("Orange")
val isShort = lengthFilter(5)

list.filter { (isFruit && isShort) (_) }
```

As you can see the benefit of this approach compared to the `withFilter` approach is that you can combine the predicates arbitrarily

Comment: It does not look like the filters can be added dynamically here.  Assuming dynamic addition is not a requirement, why not simply create a `nameAndLengthFilter(s: String, i: Int): (String) => Boolean`?

Comment: @BAR Updated with dynamic predicate append example

Comment: I am using filters dynamically by adding them if the `if` statement that wraps them is true.  So I still could not use your example dynamically enough with as concise of code as the `withFilter` approach.  Your answer did show me some interesting points so +1 for you.

Comment: I realized your Predicate code is basically the implementation of `withFilter` in `TraversableLike`  https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala

Comment: _"I still could not use your example dynamically enough"_ Sure you can dynamically add to a `Predicate` as you can to a `WithFilter`. However, for your particular use case where you only need `&&` filter chaining, there is no doubt that the library supported method is just better to use. It would be interesting to add additional filter chaining methods like `||` or `!` to the `WithFilter` class instead, but my preliminary attempts failed due to access modifiers.

Comment: Your right about the dynamic usage, I misspoke.  The `!` case is implemented by the standard library using `filterNot`. In the case one wants to use `||` remember that three `nots` and an `and` can make an `or` gate.  Now trying to implement that with the library as is gets more complicated than your example.  And since in my actual use case I could definitely need an `or` filter, I will be using your example in my code.

Comment: Please check out this new question when you can.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659506/scala-implicit-class-with-multiple-predicate-types  Thanks again for the example, lots of good points to study there!

Answer (score 1):

Consider also a [view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3361478/3189923) on the filters, like this,

```
list.view.filter(nameFilter("Apples")).filter(lengthFilter(5))
```

This prevents intermediate collections, namely for each entry in `list` it applies the subsequent filters.

Comment: This is closely related to `withFilter`.  I have been studying its implementation code, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: After further comparing the `withFilter` and `view` implementations I have found that although `view` does not create any lists, it does have to traverse twice, once for each filter, albeit on a limited view after the first filter.  While using `withFilter` allows for the list to be traversed once by checking for both filter conditions simultaneously.