# Scala - Optional Predicate

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I was informed to use this interesting piece of code, but my use case requires it to do a bit more than is currently possible.

```
  implicit class Predicate[A](val pred: A => Boolean) {
    def apply(x: A) = pred(x)

    def &&(that: A => Boolean) = new Predicate[A](x => pred(x) && that(x))
    def ||(that: A => Boolean) = new Predicate[A](x => pred(x) || that(x))
    def unary_! = new Predicate[A](x => !pred(x))
  }
```

Some use case boilerplate:

```
type StringFilter = (String) => Boolean

def nameFilter(value: String): StringFilter = 
    (s: String) => s == value

def lengthFilter(length: Int): StringFilter = 
    (s: String) => s.length == length


val list = List("Apple", "Orange", "Meat")
val isFruit = nameFilter("Apple") || nameFilter("Orange")
val isShort = lengthFilter(5)

list.filter { (isFruit && isShort) (_) }
```

So far everything works ok.  But say that I want to do something like this:

```
  val nameOption: Option[String]
  val lengthOption: Option[Int]

  val filters = {

    nameOption.map((name) =>
      nameFilter(name)
    ) &&
    lengthOption.map((length) =>
      lengthFilter(length)
    )
  }

  list.filter { filters (_) }
```

So now I need to `&&` an `Option[(A) => Boolean]` If the Option is None then simply disregard the filter.

If I use something like:

```
def const(res:Boolean)[A]:A=>Boolean = a => res

implicit def optToFilter[A](optFilter:Option[A => Boolean]):A => Boolean = optFilter match {
  case Some(filter) => filter
  case None => const(true)[A]
}
```

I have the problem of `||` with one filter set to true. I can solve this by changing true to false but then the same problem exists with `&&`.

I could also take this approach:

```
  implicit def optionalPredicate[A](pred: Option[A => Boolean]): OptionalPredicate[A] = new OptionalPredicate(pred)

  class OptionalPredicate[A](val pred: Option[A => Boolean]) {
    def apply(x: A) = pred match {
      case Some(filter) => filter(x)
      case None => trueFilter(x)
    }

    def &&(that: Option[A => Boolean]) = Some((x: A) =>
      pred.getOrElse(trueFilter)(x) && that.getOrElse(trueFilter)(x))

    def ||(that: Option[A => Boolean]) = Some((x: A) =>
      pred.getOrElse(falseFilter)(x) || that.getOrElse(falseFilter)(x))
  }

  def trueFilter[A]: A => Boolean = const(res = true)

  def falseFilter[A]: A => Boolean = const(res = false)

  def const[A](res: Boolean): A => Boolean = a => res
```

But something seems inherently wrong with having to convert the Predicate into an OptionalPredicate when the predicate is not the child type of an Option:

```
  implicit def convertSimpleFilter[A](filter: A => Boolean) = Some(filter)
```

Which allows:

```
ifFruit && isShort
```

I have the feeling that the Optional should tie in seamlessly with Predicate while following DRY principles.

Answer (score 3):

**See below (UPD)**

It would be good to be able to convert an `Option[Filter]` to `Filter`:

```
def const(res:Boolean)[A]:A=>Boolean = a => res

implicit def optToFilter[A](optFilter:Option[A => Boolean]):A => Boolean = optFilter match {
  case Some(filter) => filter
  case None => const(true)[A]
}
```

Then we would like to use any type that can be converted to a predicate:

```
implicit class Predicate[A, P <% A=>Boolean](val pred: P)
```

(and change usages of `pred` to `(pred:A=>Boolean)`)

```
def &&[P2:A=>Boolean](that: P2) = new Predicate[A](x => (pred:A=>Boolean)(x) && (that:A=>Boolean)(x))
```

**UPD**

`Option[A=>Boolean]` will be the real filter type.

```
implicit def convertSimpleFilter[A](filter:A=>Boolean)=Some(filter)

implicit class Predicate[A](val pred: Option[A=>Boolean]){
  def &&(that:Option[A=>Boolean]) = Some((x:A) => pred.getOrElse(const(true))(x) && that.getOrElse(const(true))(x) )
  def ||(that:Option[A=>Boolean]) = Some((x:A) => pred.getOrElse(const(false))(x) || that.getOrElse(const(false))(x) )
}
```

Comment: An empty filter should not always evaluate to `true` if the OP wants to ignore it completely. Otherwise, `||` will always be true when an empty filter is present.

Comment: I didn't know you could do `&&[P2:A=>Boolean](that: P2)` thanks!  What m-z said above is correct, same applies for `false` and `&&`.

Comment: Well, it seems that the base for filters should be `Option[A=>Boolean]`. Simple filters should be convertible to it and methods `&&` and `||` should take into consideration that the filter can be omitted.

Comment: "`&&` and `||` should take into consideration that the filter can be omitted."  Exactly.

Comment: Nice Update.  I was trying to keep `(A) => Boolean` as the filter type, and converting `Option[(A) => Boolean`]` to it.  Is there any way to do this?   Also the true and false thing is something I want to avoid, preferring to *remove the filter and the operator*.

Comment: `implicit def optToFilter` - the conversion function

Comment: If I use `implicit def optToFilter` I have the problem of `||` with one filter set to true.  I can solve this by changing true to false but then the same problem exists with `&&`.

Comment: Thus it seems that `Option` cannot be converted to `A => Boolean` for every use case.

Comment: Your update does not work with `list.filter { filters (_) }`  Error: `expected: (_) => Boolean actual: (_) => Any`

Comment: You can either add `.get` somewhere (`list.filter { filters.get(_) }` or val filter = { ... } .get). Or, you can deal with probably absent filter `filters` like the one returning `const(true)`: `list.filter { filters.getOrElse(const(true))(_) }`

Comment: Figured out I can add your `optToFilter` and `list.filter { filters }` to make it work.